# Whats wrong with my danio?

Tags: aquarium, fish, diseases, danio

I have a 29 gallon, planted tropical aquarium with 6 assorted danios, two golden bristlenose, and three rainbow kribs (two female and one male)

- Ammonia... 0 ppm
- Nitrites...0 ppm
- Nitrates... 0-5ppm
- Ph... 6.8-7.0
- Temp... 25-26°C

My tanks been running for just over 2 months now,and I've had the 6 danios just short of that... after a few days of having the bunch, one of the females (the danio in question) became very bloated overnight, but went down after a few days, and I found eggs so I'm guessing she was just preggers... but now for the past like 6 weeks, she's been even more bloated than when she was egg bound, and there are two red spots on her sides- aquired from another fish constantly rubbing against her- and there are some red lines which look like cracks almost across her belly... no pine coning of scales, swimming and eating on all tank levels... but looking a little... thicc

Wondering if it's dropsy, swim bladder, over feeding, or swelling from the bullying injuries

Comment: Do you have a picture?

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! Great you added the readings of the water test :) How many male and female danios are there? And could you please add a picture?

Answer (score 0):

I have many giant danios; they breed in my pond. They do not change shape noticeably when carrying eggs. I suspect the adult females are always carrying eggs. I expect your fish has a disease like dropsy.